# Iomega 335 GB USB Drive not being recognized

Tags: mount

I have a 335G Iomega USB hard drive Model MDHDU that my Ubuntu laptop does not recognize. It works well on Win7 & is NTFS formatted.  Any ideas on how to get Ubuntu to recognize it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a useful tool called `ntfs-config` which you can use to mount NTFS external drives.

Plug in your external drive.

Then install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

Start the application - the application should recognize that your USB external drive is available to use:

```
gksudo ntfs-config
```